# format os.scandir() output string, add resource type

Tags: python, scandir, directory-listing

The following code arose through a discovery phase, but its problems were never resolved, as it wasn't needed at the time.

On rediscovering its problems, however, it seemed like a decent example for more experienced developers to use as a launch point for schooling in one or more best practices using os.scandir(), the 'newer', or more generally acceptable method over os.listdir(). As an aside to the questions below, if you can explain why one is preferred over the other, or how they are or are not complementary, your views are welcome.

Some commented code remains, showing another attempt at inserting the node type at the beginning of the string. The while loop did not work out so well, but it does function. How to explain the why of it not working and what should replace its replacement, if anything more than greater fluency of the presently used functions, will go a long way to helping iron this out.

Main concerns are listed below with the core questions I have about making this monstrosity work for me in the development of more refined Python skills.

Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import time
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def scandir_list(basedir):

    entries = os.scandir(basedir)
    # print(entries)
    # <posix.ScandirIterator object at 0x7f5f7d0fe5e0>

    # The ScandirIterator points to all the entries in the current directory.
    # Loop the iterator and print out the content.

    with os.scandir(basedir) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            def filetype(entry):
                # result = ""
                # while result == "" or result == None:
                print('dir ' if os.path.isdir(entry) else '' , end="")
                print('file ' if os.path.isfile(entry) else '' , end="")
                print('link ' if os.path.islink(entry) else '' , end="")
                print('.. ' if os.path.ismount(entry) else '' , end="")
                    # result = 'dir ' if os.path.isdir(entry) else '' #, end="")
                    # result = 'file ' if os.path.isfile(entry) else '' #, end="")
                    # result = 'link ' if os.path.islink(entry) else ' ' #, end=""
                    # result = '.. ' if os.path.ismount(entry) else ' ' #, end="")
                # print('result: ', result)
                # return result
            resourcetype = filetype(entry)
            size = round(float(os.path.getsize(entry)/1024), 2) # does .2f formatting demonstrate presentation layer bias?
            lastmodified = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(entry))
            # print(f"{resourcetype}: {entry.name} \t\t\t\t\t Size: {os.path.getsize(entry)/1024:.2f} \t \t \t Last Modified: {time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(entry))}")
            print("{}: Size: {} kb, Last Modified: {}, Name: {}".format(resourcetype, size, lastmodified, entry.name))

scandir_list(basedir)
```

Renders output like so:

```
file None: Size: 5.76 kb, Last Modified: Sat Sep 25 07:07:28 2021, Name: app.py
dir None: Size: 4.0 kb, Last Modified: Fri Sep 24 23:59:23 2021, Name: test
dir None: Size: 4.0 kb, Last Modified: Sat Sep 25 04:15:51 2021, Name: views
```

The Problems:

(Just to be clear, the code here is about testing limits, so the method may simply present a wrong way to start...)

1.) Because the resource name is of variable length, and tabs (\t) inserted into the string format are relative (without stops), the resource name has been tacked on to the end. The desired outcome is to place the resource name in the second slot. How can resource name be put into the second slot and the string formatted in such as way as to avoid jagged edges, with minimal code -- whatever the refactor requires in terms of reorganization, or an altogether different approach?

2.) The first slot, resource name, is accompanied by None, but the cause (other print statements inline to the formation of the string) is not well known. What is your explanation and workaround?

UPDATE:

The code originally presented is intact, for all of its having tons of commented statements, mainly, it was thought, for the alternates to be reconstructed.

One way to get rid of `None` is below. The code is a bit cleaner, too, but the function and its call which have been 'flattened' out remain just in case...

```
import os
import time
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def scandir_list(basedir):
    with os.scandir(basedir) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            resdict = dict()
            resdict.update({'res': 'dir'}) if entry.is_dir() else ''
            resdict.update({'res': 'file'}) if entry.is_file() else ''
            resdict.update({'res': 'link'}) if entry.is_symlink() else ''
            # resdict.update({'res': '..'}) if os.path.ismount(entry) else ''
            resourcetype = resdict['res']
            # print("resdict: ", resdict) # what's it look like?
            size = round(float(os.path.getsize(entry)/1024), 2)
            lastmodified = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(entry))
            print("{}: Size: {} kb, Last Modified: {}, Name: {}".format(resourcetype, size, lastmodified, entry.name))
            # del resdict # not really necessary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scandir_list(basedir)
```

Comment: Why define a function that won t change inside a loop? Why so much commented print lines in your code? What do you want to have? Can you provide an example of expected result so we can help? Please reformat the question with more synthetic sentences...
(you have None because you have no return in your function, it is commented)

Comment: @VincentBénet It is a mess. It was a quick and dirty approach that really didn't work, and, as your question shows, not well thought out originally. Hopefully that will change. An update using dict.update() replaced the print statements. returns didn't work the way it had been cobbled before. Now it's formatting and maybe conditional display upon known type. Formatting has me perplexed. Any ideas about tab (\t) or alternates?

Comment: Hi, I just modify my answer to insert \t in return string in order to format in column. (note that it prevent of shift line only for 4 digits. Use string slicing to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
Your error is that your function return 'None', because you don t have return in it. Don t confuse a print and a return.

Please find bellow your code with best practices:

```
import os
import time


def scandir_list(dir_path):
    result = ""
    for entry in os.scandir(dir_path):
        stats = entry.stat()
        result += f"""{
                (
                    [
                        filetype 
                        for filetype in ['dir', 'file', 'mount', 'link'] 
                        if getattr(os.path, f"is{filetype}")(entry)
                    ] + 
                    ["Unknow"]
                )[0]
            }\tSize: {
                round(float(os.path.getsize(entry)/1024), 2)
            }kb\tLast Modified: {
                time.ctime(stats.st_mtime)
            }\tName: {entry.name}\n"""
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(scandir_list(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Here my output:

```
dir     Size: 16.0kb  Last Modified: Fri Sep 24 10:17:24 2021     Name: xxx
dir     Size: 28.0kb  Last Modified: Tue Sep  7 12:15:40 2021     Name: yyy
dir     Size: 4.0kb   Last Modified: Fri Sep 24 11:00:04 2021     Name: zzz
dir     Size: 28.0kb  Last Modified: Tue Jun 15 22:16:15 2021     Name: aaa
dir     Size: 4.0kb   Last Modified: Thu Mar 18 14:54:12 2021     Name: bbb
dir     Size: 4.0kb   Last Modified: Tue Jul 28 22:12:35 2020     Name: ccc
file    Size: 2.22kb  Last Modified: Thu Jul 22 15:44:15 2021     Name: ddd.py
```

Comment: Much cleaner code, Vincent. On my end, working out the section iterating through the various types, as this returns a string of type class `<class: 'type'>. The resource name being tagged on to the end of the string is not, to my mind, aesthetically pleasing. It was a workaround. Any ideas about making it the second value to be displayed in the string -- without jagged edges of following fields?

Comment: Code edited, please retry and it will work as desired. Green mark it if ok for you

Comment: ```def filetype(entry):
    for filetype in ['dir', 'file', 'mount', 'link']:
        if getattr(os.path, f"is{filetype}")(entry):
            return filetype
    else:
        return "Unknow"```

Yes, works perfectly changing return from 'type' to 'filetype'. The variable 'path' name is changed to 'entry' to better reflect what variable is being passed, and to avoid conflict (perceptual only) with 'os.path'. Much simpler (and complex) code. Thank you.

Comment: Benet After some follow up, and a little serendipity, it looks to me like the answer doesn't do justice to the capabilities of scandir(), particularly DirEntry, as exposed by scandir() https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry. Calls to os.path.isfile(basepath), and others, avoid using scandir's included typing, causing calls to the OS to accumulate in the code, one of the major reasons the PEP covering scandir was written and accepted as a development aimed at the standard library.  https://benhoyt.com/writings/scandir/

Comment: Yes, please visit this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result
have a look on method: `entry.stat()`. My code has been modified for time display on this documentation

Comment: filetype 
 for filetype in ['dir', 'file', 'mount', 'symlink'] 
if f"{entry}.is_{filetype}{()}" <<

Ok, for me the code is starting to look more like Javascript, but you really put Python features through their paces. In trying to refactor the conditional on the list comprehension to reflect use of `stats=entry.stat()`, I have so far been unable to have it evaluate as `gettattr()` did with `os.path.__()`. All `os.path` calls can be elimated as `stats.st_size', and `stats.st_mtime`, + are available with the single `entry.stat()`. Also += makes the code different, gathering first b4 print.